# How can i add ifconfig to Yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I build yocto for BeagleBoneBlack and it is bring up.
But i found that Yocto does not have `ifconfig`.

Could anybody tell me how to add `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 2):

**ifconfig** is part of **net-tools** package.

Yocto already supports this package and it is located under poky layer:

**[poky/meta/recipes-extended/net-tools](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-extended/net-tools/)**

All what you have to do is add it to your image, add this to your local.conf for testing, and you should add it to your main image recipe (Ex: **recipes-core/images/main-image.bb**) :

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " net-tools"
```

Comment: Please do not suggest to do that in local.conf, this is a very bad practice...

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni why do you say adding this in `local.conf` is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I found the `ifconfig` and `ip` shall be done with superuser.
I tried both without superuser and found that my knowledge about Yocto is poor.